# How can I use cellular phone in Istanbul airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, cellphones, istanbul

Suppose, I am traveling from India to Munich. My friend is traveling from Warsaw to India. Both of our transit is in Istanbul.

We arrived at Istanbul airport, and we want to talk via mobile phone.

How can we do that?

Note: my question is about using mobile phone while in transit.

Comment: Do you _need_ to talk? Can't you just message each other? That way, you can use data roaming but not spend too much money on it.

Comment: @terdon, yes, we must talk.

Comment: @terdon, besides, how expensive are you talking about?

Comment: @user366312 the amount will depend on your carrier, but my carrier, o2 de, charges 0.99eur/mb in turkey without a plan, which is a lot. You can easily end up with a sizable bill.

Comment: Yeah, it could be free or it could be _very_ expensive depending on the details of your contract. But that's why it seems more sensible to just message each other and then meet up physically in the airport.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Cheapest**

Connect to [free wifi in Istanbul airport](https://www.istairport.com/en/announcements/free-wifi-at-istanbul-airport?locale=en). You may have to approach a kiosk to connect to Wifi. It is only free for one hour. Use wisely.

**Expensive**

Enable International roaming for both and just call each other, or SMS to communicate.

**Alternate**

Make sure the terminal and flight time. When you land, see if the flight is arrived or delayed. At a predetermined time, wait at any of the [predetermined facility](https://www.istairport.com/en/passenger/airport-guide/transfer-transit-passenger-services?locale=en) and ask your friend to meet at the same time there. Once you meet, you won't need mobile phone.

<strike>**Alternate 2**</strike>

You can use an app like [Briar](https://briarproject.org/how-it-works/), which can communicate with devices connected to same wifi. You both can connect to airport wifi, without internet and communicate with each other. (Wifi firewall may block this). It won't work due to network isolation.

Comment: What is the advantage of using Briar on the free wifi instead of regular Whatsapp etc?

Comment: @lambshaanxy Briar works even without internet. The phones just needs to be on same network and it sends messages via LAN.

Comment: @AnishSheela How would two phones at the Istanbul Airport be able to connect to a publicly accessible and common LAN without getting internet access?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo connect to the same public wifi. Even if you don't login, you are in the same network.

Comment: Hopefully not too expensive: Turn off mobile data.  Turn on roaming.  Use SMS to coordinate meeting (if you get charged per day by your operator, it could be pricey.  If you get charged per message, much less so

Comment: @AnishSheela For security reasons, public WiFi networks often do “network isolation” and devices cannot “see” other devices on the same network. Also depending on how authentication is done, you could very well not have access to anything before you’ve authenticated.

Comment: Just FTR, It's inconceivable Briar would work

Comment: @Fattie Yeah. That's why I listed it last. It may or may not work.

Comment: I can assure you that an app like briar will not work in IST.

Comment: @AnishSheela Commercial wi-fi networks often use a feature called "client isolation" which prevents two connected devices from talking directly to each other

Comment: The expensive option might also not work; many mobile phone plans might not include international roaming in some countries at all, not even with extra fees. When I was in Toronto and travelled outside of Ontario (de facto outside the GTA), I could only do emergency calls.

Comment: OP could also get a travel SIM in advance that has cheap roaming in Turkey. If their phone supports eSIM this can be done without having to order a physical SIM card.

Answer (score 2):

You (and he)  can type ur passport number in machine and get free wifi for an hour. I think its more better way than finding solution to celluar phone